# (Responsive) Relative DIV containing absolute left and right image

Tags: html, css, header, responsive

I am trying to make a full width header containing two images to the left and right which scale with screen size, but when the right image collides with the left, I want the left image to scale down in size. Anyone who can nudge me in the right direction?

html

```
<div class="header">
<img src="images/header1.jpg">
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home  </a></li>
            <li>&#160; | &#160;</li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><strong>About  </strong></a></li>
            <li>&#160; | &#160;</li>
            <li><a href="blog">Blog  </a></li>
            <li>&#160; | &#160;</li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<img src="images/header2.jpg">
</div>
```

css

```
.header {

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #eac7f1; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 165px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header img {
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.header img:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}

.header img:nth-of-type(2) {
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your mentioned css both img are absolute so u can float them to right or left..

Preferable u can fix this issue with media query for small screen (ex mobile, tab ) setting up top,bottom or left, right absolute position

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.header > img{
position: relative;
width: 20%;
height: auto;
}
```

Adjust height vh value on your needs. It scales img size based on parent width